# Display input field based on selected option

Tags: javascript, html, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to display and hide certain value based on specific option selected. The options are retrieved from the database.  But I can't get it to work with this code below. Can you help me find out where I'm going wrong? I'd like to try and get this code working.

[Here is the picture of what I have been working on. What I would like to do is, when I select the leave type (Eg: Annual leave), the red A box will show and hide the blue B box & when I select Time Off leave type, the blue B box will show and red A box will hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZajNa.png)

Here is my current codes:

```js
<script>
function updateValue(value)
{
    document.getElementById('ID').value = value
}

// set a defalt value
updateValue(document.getElementById('leavetype').value)
</script>
```

```html
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM leave_balance WHERE passcodeEmp='$passcodeEmp'";
$result1= mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
?>
    <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Leave Type</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select id="leavetype" class="form-control" name="balanceID"  onchange="updateValue(this.value)" required/>
        <option selected disabled>Select Leave Type</option>
     <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
     $balanceID = $row1['balanceID'];
     $leaveName = $row1['leaveName'];?>
     <option value="<?php echo $balanceID?>"><?php echo $leaveName;?></option><br> 
     <?php }?>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

This code used to show the red A box

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">From Date</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </div><input type="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="fromDate" required/ >
                  </div>
      </div>
      
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">To </label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </div><input type="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="endDate" required/ >
                  </div>
                  </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
function updateValue(value)
{
    var selectedOption = document.querySelector('option[value="'+value+'"]').text;
    if(selectedOption == 'Time Off'){
        // show (blue B box) and hide (red A box)
    }else{
        // show (red A box) and hide (blue B box)
    }
}

// set a defalt value
updateValue(document.getElementById('leavetype').value)
```